# Poner un parámetro de números usando Random y error en Math.Random

Tags: java, netbeans

Soy algo nuevo en programación, y estoy haciendo una tarea que consiste en un programa que imprime datos de ayudantes en un textArea, del cuál tengo dos dudas.

Tengo que hacer que en el programa se muestren ciertos atributos, y usé un Override del método ToString para poder imprimirlos, la cosa es que estoy usando la clase Random de Java para que me imprima números aleatorios, pero necesito que solo imprima números arriba del 0, es decir, que salgan números del 1 al límite que estoy poniendo en el programa, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

En segunda, estoy usando math.Random porque necesito que el programa elija entre las palabras que puse en el String y las imprima aleatoriamente, pero el programa está imprimiendo la misma palabra, quería saber si alguien sabe cuál es mi error usando el math.Random

Cualquier comentario es bienvenido y gracias.

Espero haberme explicado correctamente

```
 private void accionAyudantes()
    {      
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int limiteAyudante = 6;

        String[] colorPiel = {"amarillo","morado"};
        int colorRandom = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorPiel.length);
        String colorS = colorPiel[colorRandom];   

        String[] alturaR = {"alto","mediano"};
        int alturaRandom = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (alturaR.length);
        String alturaS = alturaR[alturaRandom];


        for(int i = 0; i < limiteAyudante; i++)
        {   

            int numeroOjos = randomNum.nextInt(3); //El límite tendría que ser de 1 a 2
            String color = colorS; //Imprime la misma palabra todas las veces
            String altura = alturaS; //Imprime la misma palabra todas las veces
            int nivelCrearObjetos = randomNum.nextInt(6); //El límite tendría que ser de 1 a 5
            int nivelArreglarCosas = randomNum.nextInt(6); 
            int nivelDestructivo = randomNum.nextInt(6);         

            Ayudantes ayudante = new Ayudantes(numeroOjos, color, altura, nivelCrearObjetos, nivelArreglarCosas, nivelDestructivo);    

            txtAyudantes.setText(txtAyudantes.getText()+ ayudante.toString() + "\n");              
        }
    }  


Clase Ayudantes:

public class Ayudantes {
    private int numeroOjos;
    private String color;
    private String altura; 
    private int nivelCrearObjetos; 
    private int nivelArreglarCosas;
    private int nivelDestructivo;    


    public Ayudantes()
    {

    }

    public Ayudantes(int numeroOjos, String color, String altura, int nivelCrearObjetos, int nivelArreglarCosas, int nivelDestructivo) {
        this.numeroOjos = numeroOjos;
        this.color = color;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.nivelCrearObjetos = nivelCrearObjetos;
        this.nivelArreglarCosas = nivelArreglarCosas;
        this.nivelDestructivo = nivelDestructivo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Ayudantes:" + "numeroOjos=" + numeroOjos + ", color=" + color + ", altura=" + altura 
        + ", nivelCrearObjetos=" + nivelCrearObjetos + ", nivelArreglarCosas=" + nivelArreglarCosas 
        + ", nivelDestructivo=" + nivelDestructivo ;
    }

    }
```

[image: Como pueden ver, en color y altura imprime la misma palabra, cuando en cada vuelta debería ser una diferente, y en algunos espacios, se imprime el número 0, eso es lo que tengo que corregir]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que las palabras sean distintas tienes que calcular `alturaRandom` y `colorRandom`  dentro del for.

Para que los rangos de `randomNum.nextInt()` estén en el intervalo correcto, pasa como parámetro el límite superior y sumale uno al resultado. Ejemplo: números entre 1 y 2, `randomNum.nextInt(2) +1;`

```
private void accionAyudantes()
        {      
            Random randomNum = new Random();
            int limiteAyudante = 6;

            String[] colorPiel = {"amarillo","morado"};


            String[] alturaR = {"alto","mediano"};



            for(int i = 0; i < limiteAyudante; i++)
            {   
              int alturaRandom = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (alturaR.length);
              String alturaS = alturaR[alturaRandom];

              int colorRandom = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * (colorPiel.length);
              String colorS = colorPiel[colorRandom];

                int numeroOjos = randomNum.nextInt(2) +1; //El límite tendría que ser de 1 a 2
                String color = colorS; //Imprime la misma palabra todas las veces
                String altura = alturaS; //Imprime la misma palabra todas las veces
                int nivelCrearObjetos = randomNum.nextInt(5) +1; //El límite tendría que ser de 1 a 5
                int nivelArreglarCosas = randomNum.nextInt(6); 
                int nivelDestructivo = randomNum.nextInt(6);         

                Ayudantes ayudante = new Ayudantes(numeroOjos, color, altura, nivelCrearObjetos, nivelArreglarCosas, nivelDestructivo);    

                txtAyudantes.setText(txtAyudantes.getText()+ ayudante.toString() + "\n");              
            }
        }
```